# sed command is not working to find and replace content in yaml file?

Tags: linux, sed, scripting

I have following content in the yaml file des.yaml

```
simulator:
  enabled: false
```

i want to enable the simulator by making it true like:

```
simulator:
  enabled: true
```

by using sed command

I tried using sed command but its not working like:

```
sed -i 's|simulator\:\n  enabled\: false|simulator\:\n  enabled\:  true|' des.yaml
```

command is not throwing any error.

please help

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -i '/simulator/ {N;s/\(enabled: \).*/\1true/}' input_file
```

If the match `simulator` is found, move to the next line, if the match `enabled` is present, the value will be changed to true.

**Output**

```
simulator:
  enabled: true
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though programs like `sed` can solve the problem, a proper tool should be used, here : https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/releases/

```
yq eval '.simulator.enabled=true' des.yaml
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i '/simulator:/{n;/enabled:/s/false/true/}' file
```

Match on `simulator:`, print the line and fetch the next.

Match on `enabled:`, replace `false` by `true`.